# Deleting IE8 cache programmatically doesn't seem to work

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-8, kohana

i want to delete the cache in ie8 with
the following code

```
$this->cache= Cache::instance();
        $this->cache->delete('tuinArray');
        $this->cache->delete('intBreedte');
        $this->cache->delete('intLengte');
```

i use the kohana framework it works fine in chrome and firefox, but i just seems that ie8 keeps 
the cache stored, could anyone tell me what i need to do for ie8 too delete it.

Answer (score 2):

This is server side code, which a browser has no direct effect on. I cannot say much more without seeing some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Kohana Cache is for caching server side data. I am assuming you are having problems with Internet explorer and caching (usually one would have this problem when working with Ajax). If you are using jQuery, you can disable clientside caches using the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({ cache:false });
});
</script>
```

Even if you are using another javascript libraries, it should have a similar option where you can FORCE the browser disable AJAX caching (especially with IE).